# I want to run wpscan on Ubuntu vps server, but getting ruby errors

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

Firstly i installed wpscan on ubuntu by following these methods

```
apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev ruby-dev build-essential libgmp-dev zlib1g-dev
git clone https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan.git

cd wpscan

sudo gem install bundler && bundle install --without test development
```

Then when i run it by typing ruby wpscan.rb 
it said

```
Could not find ffi-1.9.18 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

when i run bundle install i got that output

```
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.18), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.18'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  typhoeus was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
    ethon was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
```

Help will be appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL RMV

Pre-requisites

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

1. Add the PPA and install the package

sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rvm

sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER

2. Change your terminal window
   At terminal window, click Edit > Profile Preferences, click on Title and Command tab and check Run command as login shell.

[Edit Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khf6x.png)

3.Reboot
A lot of changes were made (scripts that needs to be reloaded, you're now member of rvm group) and in order to properly get all them working, you need to reboot (in most cases a logout/login is enough, but in some Ubuntu derivatives or some terminal emulators, a shell login is not performed, so we advise to reboot).

4. Enable local gemsets
   Now enable local gemsets. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

rvm user gemsets

5. Install a ruby
   Now you're ready to install rubies. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

rvm install ruby

RVM Usage
man rvm

---

INSTALL - WPSCAN
From RubyGems

gem install wpscan

You can update the local database by using
wpscan --update

Enumerating usernames
wpscan --url https://target.tld/ --enumerate u

Enumerating a range of usernames

wpscan --url https://target.tld/ --enumerate u1-100

Doc>> https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/wiki/WPScan-User-Documentation